# SQL insert from select, but set some values by hand

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say that I have table with A LOT of columns. I have one column with primary key that has autoincrement set to 1. I want to insert a new row and in this new row I have following requirements:

- The row must have generated ID
- All non-specified columns have to be copied from row with `id='9999'`
- I have to be able to set some values of columns by hand (for example columns `name` and `age`

I have tried:

```
Insert Into demo_table
  Select * From demo_table Where id='9999';
```

However, I get this error:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'demo_table' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

What do I need:

I want to duplicate a row -> let the id be set by database (I have PK and autoincrement configured) -> set some columns by hand -> have other column's values duplicated, without specifying column names (as I have a lot of columns and their names could change in future.)

Form of solution:

I would prefer if I was able to achive this using only one query. If necessary, I have `stored procedures` available.

My question:

Is this even possible? How could I achive such query/procedure?

Comment: Its not possible, there are no generic ways of listing columns (aside from */all), you do have to specify them, thats how SQL works.

Comment: Hm, I thought I could basically combine normal insert `... (..) VALUES (..) ...` with the insert from select somehow?

Comment: You _can_ do that but you have to explicity list the all of the columns you're inserting - except for the identity column. What Dale's saying is that there's no language shortcut to say "all columns except this one" like you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answears, I've come up with kinda dumb, but "it works solution", if you're interested. Thanks for your time DaleK && AlwaysLearning :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to build sql query by table schema:

```
USE <databaseName>

DECLARE
    @SourceTableName NVARCHAR(255) = <TableName>,
    @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#IdentityCols', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #IdentityCols; 
CREATE TABLE #IdentityCols(
    ColumnName NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #IdentityCols
SELECT
    --TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1 AND TABLE_NAME = @SourceTableName
UNION
SELECT
    --o.name,
    c.name
FROM
    sys.objects o inner join
    sys.columns c on o.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE
    c.is_identity = 1 AND o.name = @SourceTableName

--STRING_AGG in SQL SERVER 2017 and greater. As aproach for early versions is cursor or loop
SELECT @SqlQuery = 'SELECT ' + STRING_AGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') + ' FROM ' + @SourceTableName
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME=@SourceTableName AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (Select ColumnName FROM #IdentityCols)


exec sp_executesql @SqlQuery
```

For more information you can see this questions:

[How can I show the table structure in SQL Server query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298433/how-can-i-show-the-table-structure-in-sql-server-query)

[How do you determine what SQL Tables have an identity column programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87747/how-do-you-determine-what-sql-tables-have-an-identity-column-programmatically)

[How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

[SQL Server Loop through Table Rows without Cursor](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6148/sql-server-loop-through-table-rows-without-cursor/)

[SQL Server loop - how do I loop through a set of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662356/sql-server-loop-how-do-i-loop-through-a-set-of-records)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, how I've solved this problem:

After I've read your comments (thanks btw) and some threads online, I've realized why I cannot do what I asked. However, I've come seen solution to similar problem somewhere, where they wanted to `select * except one specific column`, they solved it like this:

- copied the entire table
- selected from there.

I've come up with similar solution to my problem

```
-- check data, remove after testing
select * from demo_table order by ID desc;

-- create table with one column I want to duplicate
select * into Temp_demo_table from demo_table where ID=9999;

-- drop id, so it does not get included in the inter-table insert
alter table Temp_demo_table
    drop column ID;

-- update columns that I need to modify, doesn't have to have WHERE clause, becuase there's only one row there
update Temp_demo_table set MyCustomProperty='abc', name=NULL, age=NULL

-- insert the desired and edited row
insert into demo_table
    select * from Temp_demo_table;

-- drop the temp table
drop table Temp_demo_table;

-- check data, remove after testing
select * from demo_table order by ID desc;
```

I realize how inefficient this is, however the function (on my api) executing this command will not be called so often (max 100 times per day). I believe that this query could be optimized, however I do not have sufficient knowledge to do it at this moment (100% going to put it in my TODO :D).

**Edit-1:**

Just found out that you can write queries in oracle db like this:

```sql
(select * from demo_table) - (select name, age from demo_table)
```

I currentlly don't know if I can apply this to sql server, however as soon as I have an access to mssql, I'll try it out and keep this answear updated!

Comment: Thats not a bad solution, for some scenarios, but seems overkill just to avoid typing out a bunch of columns?

Comment: Oh, it's totally overkill, however the data I'm working with, has dynamic columns. There are some columns that are guaranteed, however there are some dynamic ones. I know it seems weird, but I'm currentlly rewritting one old software, and because it was implemented like this, and I have to ensure backwards compatibility, I have to implement the functionality like I described in my original question :/